# use multi query in one function and get null session exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I use `multi query` in one function (checking and save data)

```
@Component
public class ApplicantManager {

@Autowired
private AccountDAO accountDAO;

@Autowired
private RoleDAO roleDAO;

public AccountModel signUpApplicant(PersonDTO personDTO) throws ExistException {
    if (accountDAO.isExistAccountByEmail(personDTO.getEmail())) {
        throw new ExistException(AccountEntity.class, personDTO.getEmail());
    }
    AccountEntity account = new AccountEntity(new PersonEntity(personDTO));
    account.setActive(false);
    account.addRole(roleDAO.getRoleApplicant());
    return new AccountModel(accountDAO.saveOrUpdate(account));
}
```

}

and better to see my **Base Dao class** that other Dao classes impl that:

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public abstract class DAOHibernateAbstract<T extends BaseEntity> implements DAO<T> {
protected final Class<T> clazz;

protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public DAOHibernateAbstract() {
    try {
        this.clazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.debug("can't determine class from generic type!");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("can't determine class from generic type!");
    }
}

protected final Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

@Override
public final T saveOrUpdate(T entity) {
    if (null == entity) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null entity not acceptable");
    }
    Session session = this.getSession();
    session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
    return entity;
}

@Override
public final Collection<T> saveOrUpdate(Collection<T> entities) {
    if (null == entities) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null entities not acceptable");
    } else if (!entities.isEmpty()) {
        entities.forEach(entity -> this.saveOrUpdate(entity));
    }
    return entities;
}


@Override
public final void delete(T entity) {
    if (null == entity) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null entity not acceptable");
    }
    this.getSession().delete(entity);
}
@Override
public T get(Serializable identifier)
        throws NotExistException {
    if (null == identifier) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null identifier not acceptable");
    }
    T result = this.getSession().get(clazz, identifier);
    if (null == result) {
        throw new NotExistException(clazz, identifier);
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
public List<T> get() {
    List<T> results = this.getSession()
            .createCriteria(clazz)
            .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
            .list();
    return null == results ? new ArrayList<>() : results;
}
}
```

and this is my **AccountDao** class:

```
@Repository
public class AccountDAOHibernateImpl extends DAOHibernateAbstract<AccountEntity> implements AccountDAO {
   @Override
  public boolean isExistAccountByEmail(String email) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (!StringUtils.hasText(email)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null email not acceptable");
    }
    AccountEntity account = (AccountEntity) this.getSession()
            .createCriteria(AccountEntity.class, "account")
            .createAlias("account.person", "accountPerson")
            .add(Restrictions.eq("accountPerson.email", email))
            .uniqueResult();
    if (null == account)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
}
```

but when spring want to run `saveOrUpdate`(last line of `signUpApplicant` function), i see `NullPointerException` for `session`....

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.pazandish.autpress.dataaccess.baseclasses.DAOHibernateAbstract.getSession(DAOHibernateAbstract.java:44)
at com.pazandish.autpress.dataaccess.baseclasses.DAOHibernateAbstract.saveOrUpdate(DAOHibernateAbstract.java:52)
at com.pazandish.autpress.bussiness.ApplicantManager.signUpApplicant(ApplicantManager.java:54)
at com.pazandish.autpress.presentation.rest.IndexRestController.newApplicant(IndexRestController.java:170)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
... 65 more
```

what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Debug & check that the `private AccountDAO accountDAO` is get getting autowirred correctly or not. If not add the code for `AccountModel` to the question

Comment: testing and getting correctly all autowirred

Comment: Post the actual exception. Next to that your actual `@Transactional` should be on the manager class NOT the dao class. Currently you will get 3 single transactions (2 for the reads, 1 for the save) which all open a connection, setup a session etc. which is not only slow but also dangerous (the business method should either fail or succeed), although in this case it are only reads imagine what would happen if you have 2 writes and the first succeeds and the last fails, you wouldn't be able to rollback.

Comment: And where is exactly is the stacktrace? Why is your DAO class annotated with transactional, which is the duty of service-layer? Any good reason that you require transaction for read?